# Coding the Pythagoras theorem

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement, math

Hi I am a beginner at java and I'm trying to write code to solve the Pythagoras' theorem. Here's what I've done so far however I keep getting errors with an illegal starter on line 14 as well as a "class, interface, or enum expected" error on line 31.

```
public class Pythagoras{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double a1 = 5.2;
        float a = (float)a1;
        double b1 = 8.4;
        float b = (float)b1;
        double c1 = 0;
        float c = (float)c1;

        float resultC = (float)method (c);
        System.out.println(resultC);

        public static float method(float c){
            if (c = 0){
            float result = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2));
            return result;
            }

            if (b = 0){
            float result = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(a, 2));
            return result;
            }

            if (a = 0){
            float result = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(b, 2));
            return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't define a method inside a method

Comment: Are you using an IDE? It sounds like you're doing compile-time guess-and-check. Your IDE should tell you what is wrong.

Comment: For example, `if (c = 0)` won't compile.

Comment: You need to use if (a == 0)

Comment: @jhamon you can't define a method *directly* inside a method. You can if you define a local or anonymous class.

Comment: @AndyTurner  Someone also said `if (c = 0)` won't compile. Well, it will if it's inside a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a function inside the main method - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888208/writing-a-function-inside-the-main-method-java)

Answer (score 1):

In java you cannot have a method defined inside another method. You would have to pull the method `public static float method(float)` out of `main`.

There are other flaws, for example:

1. Here: `if (c = 0)` you're assigning the value.
2. `method` has return statements inside `if`s, but what if none is hit? Nothing is returned.
3. `(float)method (c)` you're casting to `float` something that is defined to be `float`.
4. Instead of `double a1 = 5.2; float a = (float)a1;` why don't you write `float a = 5.2f`?